# TPL Dataflow choosing Block to post item into it

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, block, tpl-dataflow

Please take a look at my TPL Dataflow network scheme below.
There are a list of URLs, a number of Load blocks and a Parse block.
Load blocks load HTML pages with different proxy servers and all of them linked to Parse block where CPU-bound work happens. If there were an exception during page loading, URL adds back to list.

I post URLs to Load blocks with a hand-made cycle (on pic).
My question: Is there any block type, that can help with choosing Load block to post URLs to instead my hand-made cycle? For example it will post URLs to first Load clock with .InputCount <=2.

And one more. Proxy server can become unavailable during Dataflow execution. I think if I place a BufferBlock instead URLs List, then I will be able to dynamically unlink LoadBlocks with dead proxy from this BufferBlock if there is such ability. So is there a way to dynamically unlink blocks from network?

[image: Dataflow network scheme]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any block type, that can help with choosing Load block to post URLs to instead my hand-made cycle? For example it will post URLs to first Load clock with .InputCount <=2.

What you can do is to have a single `BufferBlock` that is linked to all the load blocks. You would then set `BoundedCapacity` of the load blocks to something like 3 (1 item being processed + 2 in the input and output queues). With this setup, items will wait in the `BufferBlock` until space becomes available in one of the load blocks.

> is there a way to dynamically unlink blocks from network?

Yes, [`LinkTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194692) returns an `IDisposable` which can be used to destroy that link (by calling `Dispose()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, svick! All works fine. I have wasted two weeks debugging that cycle, and now replaced it with couple of lines.

Comment: Now I can't get how to check if `LinkTo` is `Disposed`, looks like this is a private property. I need to check if there're no alive `TransformBlocks` left this way.

Comment: @ValeO I think you'll have to track that yourself. For example, if you have a collection of the `IDisposable`s, `Dispose()` and remove it from the collection at the same time.